# Simplifying Javascript array of images

Tags: javascript, arrays, onmouseover

what is the best way to simplify this javascript array?
     I am asked to create a page that slide shows 4 pictures it will use the 
     onMouseOver and onMouseOut events. I haven't attached that part of the 
     code in here. This is where I started but it looks too long. Can 
     someone please simplify this for me? Thanks in Advance.

```
 var season = Array();
 var start = 0;
 var timeDelay=3000;

season[0]=new Image();
season[0].src="winter.jpg";
season[1]=new Image();
season[1].src="spring.jpg";
season[2]=new Image();
season[2].src="summer.jpg";
season[3]=new Image();
season[3].src="fall.jpg";

function changeSeason(){
    var size= season.length - 1;
    if( start < size ) {
         start++;
    }
    else {
         start = 0;
    }
    document.times.src= season[start].src;
    timeout=setTimeout('changeSeason()', timeDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler version that does the exact same thing...

```
var season = ["winter.jpg", "spring.jpg", "summer.jpg", "fall.jpg"];
var timeDelay=3000;
var seasonCount = 0;

function changeSeason(){
    document.times.src = season[++seasonCount % season.length];
    setTimeout(changeSeason, timeDelay);
}
```

Firstly you don't need an array of images - you're just changing the src attribute so you just need an array of strings.  I also simplified the `changeSeason()` function so that it increments `seasonCount` and `% season.length` means that it will be reset to 0 when it reaches the array length.

This assumes that you start the slideshow on winter, as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the code you could use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over a list of image sources, then convert them to HTMLImage elements with the source set

```js
var sources = ['winter.jpg', 'spring.jpg', 'summer.jpg', 'fall.jpg']

var seasons = sources.map(function(src) {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = src
  return img
})

console.log(seasons)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, You use only src property of the element.
What's about keeping paths only?

```
var season = ['winter.jpg', 'spring.jpg', 'summer.jpg', 'fall.jpg'];
```

and

```
document.times.src = season[start];
```